# scroll a webpage using selenium webdriver in c #

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to scroll a webpage using selenium web driver  in c #? Currently i am not able to scroll down a  web page .I  don't need to know how to scroll an element.

Comment: Can i show it in JAVA?

Comment: Hi Kishan, if its using javascript, it wont be useful because i am using selenium with c#.

Comment: File scrFile = (driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE));  

  FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\Selenium\\screenshot2.png"));

Use this lines and screenshot is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actually you can do is, you can check the element till where you want to scroll down and perform an action,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("youElementID"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(element);
act.perform();
```